# R & dplyr: how to include more columns from the original data frame/data table after summarise()?

Tags: r, dplyr

Phrased differently, how do you aggregate one column (e.g. the `column`) while keeping another the same (e.g. the `location`)?

This MWE illustrates my problem. How would I add back in the `location` column after doing a `summarise()`? Is there some solution that involves "going up a level," before the `summarise()` so that I can maintain the original columns?

```
test <- as.data.table(data.frame(event_id = c("A","B","A","A","B"),
                                 income = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                                 location = c("PlaceX","PlaceY","PlaceX","PlaceX","PlaceY")))

test

   event_id income location
1:        A      1   PlaceX
2:        B      2   PlaceY
3:        A      3   PlaceX
4:        A      4   PlaceX
5:        B      5   PlaceY

test %>%
  group_by(event_id) %>%
  summarise(mean_inc = mean(income))

Source: local data table [2 x 2]

  event_id mean_inc
    (fctr)    (dbl)
1        A 2.666667
2        B 3.500000
```

The following doesn't work:

```
test %>%
  group_by(event_id) %>%
  summarise(mean_inc = mean(income),
  location = location)

Source: local data table [5 x 3]

  event_id mean_inc location
    (fctr)    (dbl)   (fctr)
1        A 2.666667   PlaceX
2        A 2.666667   PlaceX
3        A 2.666667   PlaceX
4        B 3.500000   PlaceY
5        B 3.500000   PlaceY
```

My desired output is:

```
Source: local data table [2 x 3]

  event_id location mean_inc
    (fctr)   (fctr)    (dbl)
1        A   PlaceX 2.666667
2        B   PlaceY 3.500000
```

Comment: In this particular instance you can just use something like `location = unique(location)` or include `location` in the `group_by`.  Do you have a more complicated use case?

Comment: Thanks, however my data has at least 100 variables so that solution seems be hard to scale up cleanly.

Comment: Then I think this may be a better place to use `mutate` and then `distinct` with `.keep_all = TRUE` instead of `summarise`.

Comment: You should show your desired output. As indicated by the answer below, it is very unclear what you're after.

Comment: @aosmith that second solution sounds promising. could you elaborate with a full answer below? I think that's what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

I hope I have understood your desires. Do an `inner_join` to recover the missing columns (assuming they are matched 1-1 with the `group_by` argument):

```
 newtest <- test %>%
   group_by(event_id) %>%
   summarise(mean_inc = mean(income)) %>% inner_join(test[-(1:2)])
#Joining by: "event_id"
 newtest
#-----------------
Source: local data table [3 x 4]

  event_id mean_inc income location
    (fctr)    (dbl)  (dbl)   (fctr)
1        A 2.666667      3   PlaceX
2        A 2.666667      4   PlaceX
3        B 3.500000      5   PlaceY
```

It's also possible you wanted to match on both event_id and location:

```
  test %>%
   group_by(event_id,location) %>%
   summarise(mean_inc = mean(income))
#---------
#Source: local data table [2 x 3]
#Groups: event_id

  event_id location mean_inc
    (fctr)   (fctr)    (dbl)
1        A   PlaceX 2.666667
2        B   PlaceY 3.500000
```

Comment: For the second approach, the SE version of `group_by_` is useful if you want to group by everything but one column and you have a lot of them: `test %>% group_by_(.dots = names(test)[-2]) %>% summarise(mean_inc = mean(income))`

Answer (score 1):

An option might be to use `mutate` and then pull out just one value per group via `distinct`.

The usefulness of this would depend on the real use case:  this seems most useful if your new variable has the same name as the original variable it summarizes.  Otherwise you would end up having your original, unsummarized variable in the final dataset.

`distinct` works here because the object is still grouped.

```
test %>% 
    group_by(event_id) %>%
    mutate(income = mean(income)) %>%
    distinct()

Source: local data table [2 x 3]

  event_id   income location
    (fctr)    (dbl)   (fctr)
1        A 2.666667   PlaceX
2        B 3.500000   PlaceY
```

In *dplyr_0.4.3.9000* you would need `.keep_all = TRUE` in `distinct`.